# Выдает ошибку AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datatime'

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now()
frame = pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv', sep='\t', header=0)
frame[frame.Birth >= pd.datatime(1985,1,1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо datetime вместо datatime.
Посмотрите комментарий. У Вас просто опечатка.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now()
frame = pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv', sep='\t', header=0)
frame[frame.Birth >= pd.datatime(1985,1,1)] #Вот тут опечатка. Надо datetime вместо datatime
```

Comment: исправил, спасибо, теперь ошибка TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str

Comment: испрвил ошибку frame.Birth = frame.Birth.apply(pd.to_datetime)